# Group and multiply columns with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm trying to multiply 2 columns until get a desired value(8), but i need to group first, also need to keep the first mult if the values is already under the desired valued (This part is the problematic)

| MPRO | ID | Nuevo_I | Nuevo_P |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ID1 | 5 | 3 |
| 1 | ID1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | ID1 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | ID2 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | ID2 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | ID3 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | ID1 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | ID2 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | ID2 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | ID2 | 2 | 1 |

Desired Output:

| Macroproceso | ID | Nuevo_I | Nuevo_P | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ID1 | 5 | 3 | 15 |
| 1 | ID1 | 2 | 3 | 6 |
| 1 | ID1 | 1 | 3 | DONE |
| 1 | ID2 | 2 | 3 | 6 |
| 1 | ID2 | 1 | 3 | DONE |
| 1 | ID3 | 3 | 2 | 6 |
| 2 | ID1 | 3 | 4 | 12 |
| 2 | ID2 | 3 | 2 | 6 |
| 2 | ID2 | 3 | 1 | DONE |
| 2 | ID2 | 2 | 1 | DONE |

I have tried with this code:

```
A = (
        df['Nuevo_I'].mul(df['Nuevo_P'])
        .groupby([df['MPRO'], df['ID']])
    )

B = A.le(8)..groupby([df['MPRO'], df['ID']]).shift(fill_value=False)
```

Hope anyone could give me hand, thanks!

Comment: Your input and output are not consistent, you sometimes have ID2, sometimes ID3 ;)

Comment: MY bad, i just edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
# compute the product
s = df[['Nuevo_I', 'Nuevo_P']].prod(axis=1)

# identify values after the first value < 8
m = (s.le(8).groupby([df['MPRO'], df['ID']], group_keys=False)
      .apply(lambda x: x.shift(fill_value=False).cummax())
    )

# mask
df['F'] = s.mask(m, 'DONE')
```

Output:

```
   MPRO   ID  Nuevo_I  Nuevo_P     F
0     1  ID1        5        3    15
1     1  ID1        2        3     6
2     1  ID1        1        3  DONE
3     1  ID2        2        3     6
4     1  ID2        1        3  DONE
5     1  ID3        3        2     6
6     2  ID1        3        4    12
7     2  ID2        3        2     6
8     2  ID2        3        1  DONE
9     2  ID3        2        1     2
```